# GCM does not show registration ID on first time execution?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to run demo SamplePush application of GCM. When I install it first time the textview show me blank when I again run it I can see the registrationID on textview.

The tutorial I am referring to is: http://android.amolgupta.in/2012/07/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-tutorial.html

Does anyone know why this is so? Is there is any solution to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the fact that this is a asyncron operation. You fire one intent to request an ID and at some point you get a Broadcast with the ID which then gets saved

Comment: Thanks for replying. Is there is any way to show that ID on first time only?

Comment: what do you mean by first time only?

Comment: then you do not have the ID yet - I think it would be better if you describe your use-case

Comment: From where i can get my use-case? And i able to see my registration ID on logcat but not on textview.

Comment: you have to set the textview's text at a different time ( after you got the ID ) - you have a hook for that in your GCMBaseIntentService - there is a method onRegistered